# Acumatica REST API - StockItem - how to use multiple product id in request

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am using the Acumatica REST endpoint https://companyName/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/6.00.001 in my application

I am using the URL https://companyName/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/6.00.001/StockItem?$filter=InventoryID eq '123456'&$expand=WarehouseDetails to fetch info about a Product and to get complete warehouse details

My query is how to use multiple product id's in single request, so that to get info about multiple products in single request to Acumatica Erp REST Url.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a generic GET request in order to have a list of all the records in that entity, you can append a specific ID at the end to select a single entity or you can use filters in order to restrict that list.

you might want to take a look at the following article from the Acumatica Help section:

**Parameters for Retrieving Records** : 
https://help-2018r2.acumatica.com/(W(3))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=c5e2f36a-0971-4b33-b127-3c3fe14106ff

but basically you will need to use different condition than "eq" in order to match more value. Even though there is no "in" condition

Comment: Do you have any more information on how you would do this?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to do this?  This would be helpful in multiple cases.  For example I'm hoping to retrieve shipments with a status of "Completed" OR "Confirmed"

Comment: Also, the documentation you posted says the REST API supports ODATA URI convention, however ODATA supports 'or' and it appears Acumatica does not?